# How to reuse Django app into another project

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-apps, django-project-architect

I have made a user registration app in a Django project.
I want to add this app (reuse) into another project.
How can I do this ?

Comment: try copying the app folder to your new project and installing the app in settings of your new Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has the feature to create Reusable App.

please refer this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/reusable-apps/)